# visual basic error in referencing SNMP class

Tags: vb.net, snmp

I have created an SNMP class

And then i want to test this class,so I create a program which imports this class…

```
Imports SNMPClass

Module Module1

End Module



Public Class SimpleSNMP

Public Sub Main(ByVal argv As String())

Dim commlength As Integer, miblength As Integer, datatype As Integer, datalength As Integer, datastart As Integer

Dim uptime As Integer = 0

Dim output As String

Dim response As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}

Dim conn As New SNMP()



Console.WriteLine("Device SNMP information:")



' Send sysName SNMP request

response = conn.[get]("get", argv(0), argv(1), "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0")

If response(0) = &HFF Then

Console.WriteLine("No response from {0}", argv(0))

Return

End If



............
```

I got an error in this line

```
 Dim conn As New SNMP()
```

Which says “SNMPClass.SNMP is not accessible in this context because it is friend”..

I m using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: I think the relevant code is missing. In the error line, click on SNMP and press F12. It should take you to a library class.

Comment: What is `SNMPClass`? Never seen that in the BCL...

Comment: i think there is some technical prob.. am unable to post my code :-|

Comment: @ Cody Gray
I have  created an SNMP Class which has its own methods ,,so that instead of importing builtin class i am importing my class for SNMP to perform simpel SNMP function i.e get ,getnext etc.. !

Comment: Yeah, but you didn't show us the code for that class, so how are we supposed to know anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have all of your code to verify this is the case, I believe the following article from Microsoft about this error will address your issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814319